# Iframe's overflow problem

Tags: css, iframe, overflow

I have a simple page that contains an iframe. The iframe contains a page with some divs. When I open the embedded page separetely it works very well. The div that should be overflowed is overflowed. But when I open the container site it is not. Here are my codes:

**Container page:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>

    <style type="text/css">
            #content{
                margin: auto;
                width: 500px;
                height: 1000px;
                background: green;
            }

            #frame{
                width:202px; 
                height:302px; 
                overflow: visible;
            }
    </style>

  </head>

  <body>
        <div id="content">
            <iframe id="frame"
                src="http://localhost:8080/webApp/view/test/embeddable.html" 
                scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0">
            </iframe>           
        </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Embeddable page:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            width: 200px;
            height: 300px;
            overflow: visible;
            border: 1px solid yellow;
        }

            #id1{
                margin: auto;
                width: 500px;
                height: 10px;
                border: 1px solid white;
                background: red;
                margin-top: 20px;
            }
    </style> 
  </head>

  <body>
        <div id="id1"></div>        
  </body>
</html>
```

id1 should be overflowed but it isn't. I have set all the important div's "overflow" property to "visible" (even if it is the default). I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In short, it is not possible to have an overflowed iframe. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176572/is-there-a-way-to-have-content-from-an-iframe-overflow-onto-the-parent-frame) gives an explanation.

To achieve the similar effect you're after, you're better off use AJAX to inject the embedded page into a div, and make the div overflow.