# Display dropdown out of iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tableau-api

My application runs in an iframe of another web app (Tableau server). The dropdown in my application should render outside the iframe i.e. on another app's DOM.

I have utilized [Sumoselect](http://hemantnegi.github.io/jquery.sumoselect/) JQuery plugin for dropdown options in my app which is added to the Tableau dashboard as an [extension](https://tableau.github.io/extensions-api/) which would run inside an iframe.

I've tried to change the position and z-index of my app to absolute 
and 1000 according to this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18213299/iframe-z-index-for-drop-down-menu/18214134) but that did not help.

Modifying the styles of Sumoselect JQuery plugin also did not help.

```
// Sumoselect css modification
.SelectClass {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1000;
}

// iframe modification 
iframe {
    border: 0px none;
    width: 1090px;
    height: 167px;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

Any help would highly be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Please check, if your application and parent App is on the same domain then you can easily render or dynamically create a dropdown in parent App. If your domain is different then cross origin policy wouldn't allow you to access the element of parent.

If in the same domain. Please utilize below using javascript/jquery code:-

```
$(parent.document).find('body').append(put your dropdown code html);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, Akash for the response. Both applications have different domains but using native HTML select with few CSS tweaks would come out of the iframe. The same is not working for plugins.