# How to show HTML element outside iframe boundaries

Tags: html, css, iframe, xhtml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to have content from an IFRAME overflow onto the parent frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176572/is-there-a-way-to-have-content-from-an-iframe-overflow-onto-the-parent-frame)

I am looking for a possible workaround for the following situation:

There is an element with the "**position: absolute**" style inside a page loaded into an iframe element. According to the iframe specifics and several posts on this forum ([Is there a way to have content from an IFRAME overflow onto the parent frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176572/is-there-a-way-to-have-content-from-an-iframe-overflow-onto-the-parent-frame)), there is no way to show the "position: absolute" element outside the iframe boundaries.

However, there seems to be an exception: the native [select/option](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp) element is shown outside the iframe borders:

MainPage.htm:

```
<iframe src="WindowPage.htm" style="height: 50px; width: 50px"></iframe>
```

WindowPage.htm:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <select>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
    </select>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there any possible style/settings (may be HTML5/CSS3, etc.) to achieve this behavior for the "position: absolute" element inside the iframe?

Comment: Do you mean to say entire select/option element show outside or just the dropdown?

Comment: @Quentin: Yes, I have already mentioned this in my question.

Comment: @dotNETbeginner: Just an option element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer: no.

You really have next to no control over the contents of an iFrame, stylistically or otherwise. Anything that the source page's CSS declares will trump anything you try anyway.

Plus, as mentioned in link mentioned in the comments, there are security implications around iFrames that make this kind of necessary.

Comment: Absolutely, but what about the "option" element?

Comment: Where are you seeing an exception for the option element? As it stands, even in a regular page, <option> elements are notoriously difficult to style. I highly doubt you'd be able to affect any change on one inside an iFrame.

Comment: Here :) http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=http://support.microsoft.com:80/support/kb/articles/q177/3/78.asp&NoWebContent=1

Comment: @Mikhail: link down, do you remember the essentials or have a memento/snapshot at hand?