# DevExpress popup does not overflow outside of iframe

Tags: asp.net, css, iframe, devexpress

I included a FilterControl inside an iframe popup. When I open the column selector (or any other DevExpress combobox) the popup does not 'overflow' outside of the frame. What I want is to be able to see the contents of the popup outside of the frame, instead of having to scroll down to see the whole option list.

Basically this is how it looks like (obviously not actual code):

```
<iframe>
  <dx:ASPxFilterControl/>
</iframe>
```

Is this possible? All of our popups in the site are created in the same way and we wouldn't want to use different popups just because of this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to have content from an IFRAME overflow onto the parent frame?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/176572/is-there-a-way-to-have-content-from-an-iframe-overflow-onto-the-parent-frame)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's impossible. This is how iframes work. Check the following threads:

[How to show HTML element outside iframe boundaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12802967/)

[Is there a way to have content from an IFRAME overflow onto the parent frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176572/)