# Showing popover outside of iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, iframe

In Boostrap, how can a "onHover" popover in an iFrame be shown outside of it?

For example:

```
<div class="has_popover"></div>

<iframe class="has_event><input></iframe>
```

When someone puts focus into `input`, I'd like to show a popover on the div outside the iframe. Is that possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to have content from an IFRAME overflow onto the parent frame?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/176572/is-there-a-way-to-have-content-from-an-iframe-overflow-onto-the-parent-frame)

Answer (score 0):

Have the iframe element's `onHover` event use the `window.parent.` nomenclature:

```
window.parent.callPopover();
```

Both the parent document and the iframe have to be on the same domain. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9393545/1430996) for more.