# How to display html webresource on top of MS dynamcis CRM main page

Tags: html, dynamics-crm, datetimepicker, webresource

I have created a HTML web resource which contains jQuery DateTime Picker control customized as per my needs. When I add it to the CRM entity page it shows an input fields as usual. However when I click into this input field, the DateTime picker control gets opened but not visible completely on the CRM page.

Can anyone help me to get this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that this is an issue with iframes and browser security. Please see [This Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176572/is-there-a-way-to-have-content-from-an-iframe-overflow-onto-the-parent-frame) for the reasoning.

I see that you have two options. You can use unsupported methods to add the date picker control to the CRM form page, which would take some somewhat-serious hacking or you could expand the web resource to accommodate the date picker control.