# Bootstrap clock picker outside iframe

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, modal-dialog, bootstrap-datepicker

I am using bootstrap modal for showing modal window. For modal body I am using `iframe` so that if I submit form I can get response on the same modal window.

My `iframe` is like :

```
  <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-4by3">
        <iframe  seamless="seamless" class="embed-responsive-item" src="schedule"></iframe>
  </div>
```

I am using [ClockPicker](http://weareoutman.github.io/clockpicker/) plugin to pick the time. But when Clock Picker appears it hides behind the scroll. I have changed z-Index of clock picker but it doesn't seem to work.

[image: Modal window with iframe]

Any help ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to have content from an IFRAME overflow onto the parent frame?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/176572/is-there-a-way-to-have-content-from-an-iframe-overflow-onto-the-parent-frame)