# show DIV inside IFRAME out of the container

Tags: html, css, iframe

I have created a custom dropdown with ul/li/div which works fine,
that dropdown is inside a page loaded in an iframe. 
Problem:
to open the dropdown and see the items over the iframe. Right now what happen is that the  iframe.
I have just tried to change z-index without any success.
any suggestions will be  very helpful
thanks

michele

[image]

Comment: To my knowledge, this is not possible.

Answer (score 2):

Using an iFrame? No, it's not possible.

@JKirchartz is correct. Check out:

[Is there a way to have content from an IFRAME overflow onto the parent frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176572/is-there-a-way-to-have-content-from-an-iframe-overflow-onto-the-parent-frame)

Answer (score 1):

What you're suggesting is not possible, however there are other ways to set the parent content from within an iFrame.
I'd recommend you take a look at the [window.parent](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_parent.asp) property which allows you to manipulate the parent of the iFrame.
An example of the usage of this is:
**index.html:** (Parent)

```
<p id="test">Hello!</p>
<iframe src="otherpage.html"></iframe>
```

**otherpage.html:** (Child)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.parent.document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "Hello World!";
</script>
```

This example will change `Hello!` on the parent page to `Hello World!` from JavaScript code executed from within the iFrame. You'll be able to manipulate the `<ul>` tag this way using the `innerHTML` property to add new `li` tags and anything else that you wish to do with it.