# How to open IFrame within fixed size

Tags: css, iframe, height, width

I have an iFrame as follow:

```
<iframe id="rffd74891-556d-4b13-bb19-5b486db41ec4" src="/DGS.DGSAPI.UI/ReportViewerWebForm.aspx" style="height: 483px; width: 1466px;"></iframe>
```

I have specified height and width already but if the content is larger than that, it expands and show scrolls. What can be done to make the content fit into a specified size so it doesn't create scrolls?
Actually it increases the width at runtime of iFrame. How can I force it load within say width of 500px and not change iframe's width as it loads content?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/176572/is-there-a-way-to-have-content-from-an-iframe-overflow-onto-the-parent-frame is probably related.