# How to display popup image of qtip outside of fancybox

Tags: jquery, fancybox, qtip2

I have a requirement that,
I have fancybox popup opened, and inside of that fancybox I have an **`<a>`** tag, On hover to this **`<a>`** tag I am showing an Image as **another popup** using **qTip2** library.
but this image I want to show **outside/beyond** the `fancybox` popup.
For this I have done this:

```
$('a.class-qtip2-image-a').each( function(){
    $(this).qtip({
        content: {
            text: $(this).next('img'),
        },
        style: {
            classes: 'qtip-bootstrap higher-z-index',//qtip-bootstrap
        },
        position: {
            viewport: $(window),
        }
    });
});
```

**Update:** Fancybox code:-

```
$('.cls-process-popup').fancybox({
    'width' : '100%',
    'height' : 'auto',
    'autoScale' : true,
    'transitionIn' : 'elastic',
    'transitionOut' : 'elastic',
    'type' : 'iframe',
});
```

[image]

Comment: Show your fancybox code

Comment: I have added fancybox related code..

Comment: Since your are displaying the content inside an `iframe` (that's why I wanted to see your fancybox code) I don't think it's possible (for many reasons but most importantly security) ... check this http://stackoverflow.com/q/176572/1055987 for further reference

Comment: you can change my fancybox's `type`and then can you make it possible ?

Comment: If the content is `inline`, most likely

Comment: Looks like it would be better to update to fancyBox3