# When using iframe, how to maintain always a maximum height Angular 4

Tags: css, html, iframe, scroll, overflow

First of all, using Angular 4, bootstrap 3, html 5.

Right now, I have an iframe `<iframe src="http://test.test"></iframe>` with the style

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}
iframe {
    display: block;
    border: none;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
}
```

When the html pops, the height is correct (and I have no scrollbar), but when the content of the iframe page changes, a scroll bar appears. My objective is to not have the scrollbar in the iframe, NEVER.

EDIT1: Already tried `overflow: hidden;`, does not work.

EDIT2: I do not want content to spill onto the parent page.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to have content from an IFRAME overflow onto the parent frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176572/is-there-a-way-to-have-content-from-an-iframe-overflow-onto-the-parent-frame)

Comment: I don't see how this is related to the other question.  This one is about preventing scrollbars from appearing in an iframe; it doesn't look like OP wants the content to spill onto the parent page.

Comment: Exactly, but maybe the first answer is related to this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue and I add a js script to take the full innerHeight, try this, you can also implement it onload of the window (you can use id, but i always show class example because it can be used multiple times) :

```
<script>
    window.onresize = function() {
        var frame = document.getElementByClassName('myFrameClass')[0];
        frame.style.height = window.innerHeight;
    }
</script>
```

**EDIT** : must have scrolling="no" on the iframe tag, and the overflow: hidden css rule for inner content

Comment: html5.. cant do scrolling="no"

Comment: and seamless="seamless" ?

Comment: Nothing... I think I need to do click actions :S

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `overflow: hidden` to your styles.